# How can view application errors in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android studio.

Previously used eclipse to develop android apps but Google stopped it.

So i am trying to learn how to develop apps using android studio.

I have noticed that if an application gets an error and stops , i dont get any log information on the cause of the error as it was the case in eclipse.

It is possible to view application errors in android studio?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Ronald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the `Android Monitor` at the bottom row.

[image]